# Forms get glitchy with too many nested paragraphs

Tags: 8, performance, paragraphs

We have built a complicated structure for building pages out of paragraph components, but are now quickly running into performance limitations.

It seems that the node form is monolithic, and is built, submitted and cached entirely for each operation (eg. expanding, adding, deleting or removing paragraph items). It barely takes a few dozen items before the serialized form array hits limits on mysql query size or PHP's memory limit, or other silent failures that cause data to be lost in unpredictable ways.

Is there a solution that would allow editing a single paragraph in its own form (eg. a modal) rather than the whole node? I would really rather not refactor the whole content structure to use entity-referenced nodes instead of paragraphs...

Comment: we have a test that creates up to a hundred paragraphs and while it is slow, we haven't seen any errors. But yes, it is quite monolitic. There are various issues for trying to improve that, like only saving paragraphs that have changed, you could try setting some nested paragraphs to closed to keep the form structure down. You could try to have fewer paragraphs by making the paragraph types less granular. You could also try to convert some to entity references and e.g. use inline entity form, but there is no general solution.